# Get the order fee item details in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, fee

I try to get the name of the fee attached to my order in Woocommerce, I get an array but I don't know how to get the name.

I tried with function `get_name ()` but it does not work.

```
$the_order->get_items( array( 'line_item', 'fee', 'shipping' ) );
```

Raw data output:

```
[137] => WC_Order_Item_Fee Object
        (
            [extra_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [tax_class] => 
                    [tax_status] => taxable
                    [amount] => 
                    [total] => 
                    [total_tax] => 
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 7795
                    [name] => Frais de réservation
                    [tax_class] => 0
                    [tax_status] => taxable
                    [amount] => 
                    [total] => 35
                    [total_tax] => 0
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To access and to use properties on Order Fee items you need to use the [WC_Order_Item_Fee](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Fee.html) methods **using first a foreach loop** this way:

```
// (optional if not defined) An instance of the WC_Order object
$the_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Iterating through order fee items ONLY
foreach( $the_order->get_items('fee') as $item_id => $item_fee ){

    // The fee name
    $fee_name = $item_fee->get_name();

    // The fee total amount
    $fee_total = $item_fee->get_total();

    // The fee total tax amount
    $fee_total_tax = $item_fee->get_total_tax();
}
```

Tested and works